# Wifi USB Adaptor not getting enough power

Tags: 12.04, wireless, connection

My wireless usb adapter is a Rosewill RNX-N2LX and it worked perfectly on ubuntu 12.04.3 and above but in ubuntu 12.04.1 the status of the connection says connected but there is no internet connection. I've tried connecting to an open network too. My wireless adapter light blinks at a constant rate when it's not getting enough power and it's doing that on 12.04.1. The adapter has 2 usbs connected to its mini-b connector goes into the adapter; one main usb that holds the data and another which I presume it to be a power cable, I'm guessing they're connected in parallel for higher current? As for ubuntu 12.04.1 I think that it's not recognizing the second usb as a device so it limits the current to a minimum to save power. I'm stuck using 12.04.1 because AMD has dropped the support for my graphics card (Radeon HD 4250) for the kernels on 12.04.3 and onward. For my driver to work I need to have my x-server version 1.12 or lower. My other option was to downgrade my x-server but that would only be a temporary solution and can cause corruption in the long run. I need a way to permanently have 2 USB slots activated as if a device is on both of them activating it. In short I need Ubuntu to recognize the second USB as a device and give it the full power it needs.

```
lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0535 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0b38:0010 Gear Head 107-Key Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8174 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

Comment: "The adapter has 2 usbs connected to its mini-b connector goes into the adapter; one main usb that holds the data and another which I presume it to be a power cable, I'm guessing they're connected in parallel for higher current?"  YES

Comment: Nice now how can I get it working?

Comment: Are you sure a driver exists and loads in 12.04.1? What does this tell us? lsusb

Comment: @chili555 I posted lsub mate

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the powersave on the USB bus by doing a `sudo su` and invoking:

```
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/control ; do echo "on" >$i ;done
```

Maybe it will work for you.

Comment: Sorry mate it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your device uses the driver r8712u. Confirm:

```
lsmod | grep -e rtl -e r8712u
```

See if there are any informative clues in the message logs:

```
dmesg | grep r8712u
```

Also check for clues here:

```
nm-tool
```

Please temporarily turn off N speeds in the router and try these tests again.

Since it worked in newer kernel versions, I suggest you install the newer drivers backported to 12.04.1:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.8-precise-generic
```

Reboot and give us your report.

Comment: Here's a link for a screenshot of the outputs: [link](http://img34.imageshack.us/img34/2631/ryhr.png)

Comment: And also the connection information shows that I have an ip address so it's connected to the internet but there is no access. System monitor shows that the receiving data is jumping from 50 bytes/s to 0, but sometimes I get a high spike up to 300 bytes/s, most of the time staying at 0.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: My computer is not connecting to the network anymore. It's a secure WPA2 network.

Comment: But apparently in should work right out of the box. [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Device/Rosewill%20RNX-N2LX)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a self-powered USB hub with the WIFI adapter? If you are experiencing low power at the USB ports, this might help.